# Txt file into a double 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am trying to read a txt file into a array of doubles. I am using the following code which reads every line of the file:

```
String fileName="myFile.txt";
try{

    //Create object of FileReader
    FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

    //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

    //Variable to hold the one line data
    String line;

    // Read file line by line and print on the console
    while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {

        System.out.println(line);

    }

    //Close the buffer reader
    bufferReader.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" 
        + e.getMessage());                      
}
```

However I want to store the txt file into a 2d double array.
I ve tried the above to load also the dimension of the txt. But I am having problems with the exceptions catch (NoSuchElementException e), it seems that it couldnt read the file.

```
try {

        while (input.hasNext()) {

            count++;
            if (count == 1) {

                row = input.nextInt();
                r = row;
                System.out.println(row);
                continue;
            } else if (count == 2) {
                col = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(col);
                c = col;
                continue;
            } else {

                output_matrix = new double[row][col];

                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

                        String el = input.next();
                        Double temp = Double.valueOf(el);
                        double number = temp.doubleValue();

                        //output_matrix[i][j] = el;
                        output_matrix[i][j] = number;
                        //System.out.print(output_matrix[i][j]+" ");
                    }
                    //System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.err.println("Sfalma kata ti tropopoisisi toy arxeioy");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());       //emfanisi tou minimatos sfalmatos
        input.close();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        System.err.println("Sfalma kata ti anagnosi toy arxeioy");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? Did you read the tutorials about [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)?

Comment: My problem is how can I convert string line into a arrayList of doubles.

Comment: So try to store, where is the problem? Reader works normally.

Comment: The one problem is what you don't know at first how many rows you have in file. One, not so good, solution is to stores all rows in one `List` then using its number create array which have `array.length` lines. Something like this` new `double[n][]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to be using the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for it, especially the [`Scanner.nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) method.

Also, if you don't know in advance the dimensions of the array - I'd suggest using an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a regular array.

Code example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> list = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
    ArrayList<Double> curr = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
    while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        curr.add(sc.nextDouble());
    }
    list.add(curr);
}
```

Comment: I used something else. I ve in the first two lines the size of the array.

Comment: I am confused, which is finally better the approach with collections or the approach with array??

Comment: @snakeplissken It depends on what you want and need. arrays are generally faster than Collection. However collection is more type safe (not in this case but in the general case), and more flexible. Collections also usually allow you to refactor the code later easily if you need to do some changes. I'd use a `Collection` unless performance is an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

At firs declare a list and collect into it all read lines:

```
List<String> tempHistory = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    tempHistory.add(line);
}
```

Then, after `bufferReader.close();` convert this `tempHistory` list into `double[][]` array.

```
double[][] array = new double[tempHistory.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < tempHistory.size(); i++) {
    final String currentString = tempHistory.get(i);
    final String[] split = currentString.split(" ");
    array[i] = new double[split.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(split[j]);
    }
}
```

It works, but as I added in comments, this is a not so good solution, and is better to use `Collections` instead of `array`.

BTW, it works even the rows lengths are different for different lines.